# Call modules in template Opencart3

Tags: templates, twig

How can I call modules directly in the template content_modules.twig (added according [INSTRUCTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141537/adding-new-modules-positions-to-opencart-3)) of Opencart3?
Like

```
{{ module_featured}}
```

?

Comment: Hi, please edit the question to describe the experiments/research you have done so far and why these didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, MandyShaw! Unfortunately I'm not a programmer. I Looked through solutions using google search but there are no unswers for my question on current and older opencart versions.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully someone in the community will be able to help you.

Comment: It is hard to say. What does `$module_featured` contain? Is it a string, is it an object? The example you gave should work as is if `$module_featured` contains a string yeah.. That is what it makes it so unclear

Comment: DarkBee, it is just an (wrong for opencart3) example of how it could be. On the place of this code should appear standard opencart3 module f.e. featured products or latest products.